# Multiple similar columns with fixed value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df like

```
ID A B C A.1 B.1 C.1 A.2 B.2 C.2
1  1 1 1  1   1   1   3  2    3
2  2 2 3  5   0   4   3  4    7
```

I have various columns from A to G like this going on...

I want is to multiple all columns starting with `A` to a fixed value of `1.5`, all with `B` as `2.3` and `C` to be left alone and D with some other number and so on..

I have a longish approach of 1st `[col for col in df.columns if 'A' in col]` then multiplying it and then repeating the same exercise again.

The problem is I have way to many columns to do this exercise again and again.

Any way of doing this in one shot?

Comment: How looks expected output?

Comment: @jezrael: Exactly the same just with new numbers i.e. the numbers after you get after multiplying

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can defined dictionary for values for columns names and scalars, get columns names before first `.` and use [`Index.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.map.html), replace missing values by `1` and last use [`DataFrame.mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html) for multiple:

```
d = {'A':1.5, 'B':2.3, 'D':5}
#to prevent ID from being multiplied, also if strings are not present, multiple by 1
df = df.set_index('ID')

df = df.mul(df.columns.str.split('.').str[0].map(d).fillna(1))
print (df)
      A    B    C  A.1  B.1  C.1  A.2  B.2  C.2
ID                                             
1   1.5  2.3  1.0  1.5  2.3  1.0  4.5  4.6  3.0
2   3.0  4.6  3.0  7.5  0.0  4.0  4.5  9.2  7.0
```

Comment: If I have to like multiple A,E,and K to same number...any change in the dictionary `d` or have to write all of them

Comment: @RahulAgarwal - Do you think multiple all columns not defined in `d` ? If yes, then  change `.fillna(1)` to `.fillna(10)` if `10` is default value

Comment: no like if both column A and G needs to get multiplied by 1.5. So,`d = {'A':1.5, 'B':2.3, 'D':5,'G':1.5}`. Do, we need to do this or there is some shorter way if two columns need to be multipled by same number?

Comment: @RahulAgarwal - Understand. I think the best is use `d1 = dict.fromkeys(['A','G','N'], 1.5)`, then `d2 = { 'B':2.3, 'D':5}` and last join together like `d = {**d1, **d2}`

Answer (score 2):

Pitifully I don't know of a way of doing it in exactly one line without defining the parameters previously or doing it one shot given you have different criteria (such as A being multiplied by 1.5, B by 2.3). However you can do each replacement in a single line:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A.1':[1,2,3],'B.1':[1,2,3],'A.2':[1,2,3],'B.2':[1,2,3],'C.1':[1,2,3]})
df.loc[:,[x for x in df if x.startswith('A')]] = df.loc[:,[x for x in df if x.startswith('A')]] * 1.5
df.loc[:,[x for x in df if x.startswith('B')]] = df.loc[:,[x for x in df if x.startswith('B')]] * 2.3
```

The output is as follows:

```
   A.1  B.1  A.2  B.2  C.1
0  1.5  2.3  1.5  2.3    1
1  3.0  4.6  3.0  4.6    2
2  4.5  6.9  4.5  6.9    3
```